# SQLite FTS External Content

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, full-text-search

I am planning on implementing search in my Android application using FTS.  The data I wish to search is spread over three normalized tables.  The tables are structured to represent two one to many relationships between data types, where LIN <1:N> NSN <1:N> Item.

I see that I can use external content inside of an SQLite FTS3 or FTS4 virtual table, but I've been unable to find any documentation on how or if I can reference multiple tables as external content in one virtual table.

Is it possible to reference multiple tables? Could I create a view and use that as an external content source for the FTS table?  What would I have to do with triggers for updates, inserts and deletes in this case?

Comment: Even if you wouldn't use external content: how would you refer from a record in the FTS table back to the original record in one of the three data tables?

Comment: A very good question. I think for now I'm going to build my search interface so that the user needs to pick what they are searching for rather than trying to search multiple types of data all in one go.

Comment: What I did for my case was that I stored id and type for each record in my FTS table. then by checking the type I knew where to look for the original record.

Comment: @Saeid Farivar how did you get data from multiple tables into the FTS table?

Comment: I am not really clear on your question? I mean I defined a fts table for example (id, title, desc, keywords, type) and then I ran different queries to read data from each different table and insert it into my fts table. does that answer your question?